# Prgm_MAWS: "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python-3.x

`MAWS.py` is a 4 years old program that uses `Amber/AmberTools` as calculation platform. Although I follow program user guide instructions, I do not know how to debug and find the solution to `raise self._value IndexError: list index out of range`

I replaced the force field(ff) specified in MAWS.py with a newer Amber ff.

As I am not familiar with python code and where the error could be generated I recommend to download the MAWS.py code from GitHub Repository:  https://github.com/igemsoftware/Heidelberg_15

```
python3 MAWS_rev1.py -b 0.01 -i 200 -s 200 -l 15 -t 0.01 -f pdb -y HYBRID Prot1a.frcmod /home/bcramer/workdir-amber/Prot_1/
['DGN', 'DAN', 'DTN', 'DCN']
Choosing from candidates ...
Constructing Ligand/Aptamer complex ...
Constructing Ligand/Aptamer complex ...
etc..................
Loading Aptamer/Ligand complex ...
multiprocessing.pool.RemoteTraceback: 
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bcramer/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/home/bcramer/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 44, in mapstar
    return list(map(*args))
  File "MAWS_rev1.py", line 1090, in initial
    ligand_range = get_ligand_range(aptamer_top.topology)
  File "MAWS_rev1.py", line 197, in get_ligand_range
    return [get_ligand(topology)[0], len(get_ligand(topology))]
IndexError: list index out of range
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MAWS_rev1.py", line 1357, in <module>
    positions_and_Ntides = loop()
  File "MAWS_rev1.py", line 1237, in loop
    pos_Nt_S_task = pool.map(initial, alphabet)
  File "/home/bcramer/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/home/bcramer/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: I am currently trying to use the same script and running into different problems. Have you checked if you could run the python script with the original forcefield? Doing that may help figure out the current problem you are facing.

Comment: The original force field ( forcefield_name = "leaprc.ff12SB" ) does not change the output error, i.e. IndexError: list index out of range.

Comment: I reinstalled Openmm and nvidia-cuda version 9.1.85, both were causing errors. It solved part of the MAWS running errors. I am using pycharm and trying to debug the program. The message is now: "be sure to install and run openmm with the same python version". So I have to check all again!

Comment: I'm not too sure if it will be possible to get it working, as they also don't support it anymore. They developed a [new](http://2017.igem.org/Team:Heidelberg/Software/MAWS) version in 2017 but I can't locate the actual python file anywhere. There are a couple of other methods floating around that people have come up with to develop aptamers/oligos for inhibition.